# Bottom text disappear on TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I use TabLayout.I have add marquee text to my second fragment.I can see the text in the editor and I don't use any code for hide or invisibility.But when I build the package and run I can't see the textview.I can see other elements and there is no problem with them.What is going wrong ?

Fragment XML

Ps: id scrollingtext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment2">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/arkaplan"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ustaraf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ustbutonliner"
                    android:layout_width="280dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/kredial"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                        android:text="@string/buycredit"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/kazanButton"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                        android:text="@string/wincredis"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />




                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>








            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/reklamlayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ustaraf"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">


                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/reklamsa2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="270dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />



            </RelativeLayout>




            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/boslukmacs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/maç15"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Kredits"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#FFDE00">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/soldaya"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
    </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vipsim"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@drawable/ok">
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kredimiz"
            android:layout_width="29dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="50"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/krediyazi"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/credit"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>





        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scrollingtext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="TEST TEST"/>







</FrameLayout>
```

TabLayout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".tabdene">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="OPEN SIGNALS">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />



        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```